# Threading error in my python script

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, module

I don't understand why I get this `threading` error by just using the threading module. It works fine without the threading module.

I searched on internet, but I don't get the appropriate answer.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace of the error you are seeing with a small code snippet that is causing the problem.

Comment: I print errors by using except Exception as ex and then print ex

Comment: And i get error in detailed @Colwin

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24604979/ @Colwin

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line before the try statement:

```
connSkt = None
```

Also modify the close part:

```
if connSkt is not None:
    connSkt.close()
```